# Trying to use StringBuilder recursively, receiving an error indicating it is not valid for the class

Tags: java, stringbuilder

EDIT: I should have mentioned, this is for an assignment that specifically calls for a recursive solution.

I'm trying to recursively check if a sentence is either a "Strict" palindrome, meaning that it respects spaces - "Able was I, ere I saw Elba!" - or if it is an "ordinary" palindrome, meaning that spaces are ignored - "A man, a plan, a canal, panama!".

If I try to run this program with just String values, I get a StackOverflow error. StringBuilder is mutable, and so I was trying to find a way to use that instead, but I can't find any examples of StringBuilder being used recursively (I assume because it makes no sense to, but I don't know why)

The code is as follows:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String userPal){


    if(userPal == null){
        return false;
    }
    else if( userPal.length() == 1 ){
        return true;
    }
    StringBuilder testAgainst = new StringBuilder();

    stringReversed(testAgainst);
    // String testAgainst = stringReversed(userPal);

    return userPal.equals( testAgainst );
}


public static StringBuilder stringReversed(StringBuilder toReverse){
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(toReverse);

    if(toReverse == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(toReverse.length() <= 1){
        return reversed;
    }

    System.out.println("This is the reverse string as it progresses: " + reversed);

    // return stringReversed( reversed.substring(1)+ reversed.charAt(0) );
    return stringReversed( reversed.substring(1, reversed.length() - 1 ) ); 

}
```

Now I'm receiving an error on the "return StringReversed" line that states: The method stringReversed(StringBuilder) in the type PalindromeCheck is not applicable for the arguments (String)

PalindromeCheck is the name of the class it's in.

I've been searching like mad, but this seems like such a foolish solution to such a nuanced problem, that I can't find an answer. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, or what's causing these issues.

If anybody here could help me understand, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you,

Kris

Comment: `StringBuilder#subString` returns a `String`. A good IDE will give you an warning if you try do do that.

Comment: I see. I'm using Eclipse, but the only error I got was the one I listed in the initial post. That does explain why I can't use it that way... Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the value in your `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder` already has a `reverse` method (but it returns a new `StringBuilder`). Either save the return value of that call or use it inline. Like,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String userPal) {
    if (userPal == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (userPal.length() < 2) {
        return true;
    }
    StringBuilder testAgainst = new StringBuilder(userPal);
    return userPal.equals(testAgainst.reverse().toString());
}
```

**or** eliminate the `StringBuilder` and iterate the first half of the `String` comparing characters with the later half. Like,

```
char[] arr = userPal.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - 1 - i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

**or** for a recursive version,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String userPal) {
    if (userPal == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (userPal.length() < 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (userPal.length() == 2) {
        return userPal.charAt(0) == userPal.charAt(1);
    }
    return userPal.charAt(0) == userPal.charAt(userPal.length() - 1)
            && isPalindrome(userPal.substring(1, userPal.length() - 1));
}
```

Comment: I knew that StringBuilder had a reverse method, but using it that way isn't recursive... is it?

I'm still relatively new to programming, and this is actually for an assignment in class. It would be simple to just use the reverse() method on the StringBuilder object, but the assignment specifically calls for a recursive solution.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound unappreciative. Thank you very much for taking the time to show me this, and to explain where I went wrong.

And thank you for showing me the recursive solution too. I'm going to run it through my mind a few times so I understand it all, and then try to implement it.

Thank you again!

Comment: The solution offered here has an issue with `""`.